# UIScrollview like transition between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, uianimation

I am trying to implement the view controller transition of a UIScrollview between view controllers, both horizontally and vertically.  I don't want to use a scrollview or a UIPageviewcontroller, I just want that transition both horizontally and vertically.  Is there a way to use UIPanGestureRecognizer and UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning to do this?

Comment: Unless UIPageViewController can not match your goal, you build yourself.

Comment: Is there an existing library or code for a reference on how to build this type of transition, particularly with a uipangesturerecognizer?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably register a `UISwipeGesture` on your current view and call:

```
UIView.transition(from: <current view>, to: <destination view>, duration: <#T##TimeInterval#>, options: <#T##UIViewAnimationOptions#>, completion: <#T##((Bool) -> Void)?##((Bool) -> Void)?##(Bool) -> Void#>)
}
```